# KML: Display multiple Placemarks

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, kml

I want to display the starting point, the destination and the route inbetween in one KML file.
My file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document id="raptor">
  <name>Raptor.kml</name>
  <visibility>1</visibility>
  <open>1</open>
  <Placemark id="start">
    <name>Start</name>
    <Point id="startpoint">
      <coordinates>
        0.16212,51.5454
      </coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark id="target">
    <name>Target</name>
    <Point id="targetpoint">
      <coordinates>
        0.06146,51.5529
      </coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark id="route">
    <name>Route</name>
    <LineString id="routelines">
      <coordinates>
        0.16212,51.5454
        0.16619,51.5445
        0.16553,51.5442
        0.05228,51.5394
        0.05113,51.5381
        0.0589,51.5528
        0.06146,51.5529
      </coordinates>
    </LineString>
  </Placemark>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

When I load it into google maps (using My Maps -> Create New Map -> Import),
it sometimes shows only the starting point, sometimes the starting point and the target point, sometimes only the route, ...

There seems to be something wrong in the way I define multiple elements. How should I do it?

**edit:**
It works when I upload the file to a server and insert the URL into the google maps search field. Is this a bug in google maps?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the file, also no issues when watching it on my maps(uploaded from PC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too checked above kml you posted in Google Earth it's working perfectly   all Start Target and Route are clearly visible.

There is no problem with the code, check once again.